# Magento 2 Vue Storefront: How to show custom attribute on product page

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.4, vue-storefront

We need to show product custom attributes on vue storefront so please help me.
[image]

Comment: I think this may help you regarding this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65393323/displaying-custom-attribute-in-product-list-page-and-product-details-page-under

Comment: No man
I need to add here: https://demo-magento2-dev.europe-west1.gcp.storefrontcloud.io/default/p/WSH12/erika-running-short.html

Comment: I guess you are looking for something like https://github.com/vuestorefront/template-magento/blob/main/modules/catalog/product/components/product-types/simple/SimpleProduct.vue to customization

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk Ya right but I don't get the custom attribute value: https://i.imgur.com/hgcP28p.png